# How to improve the UX of this filter area?

Tags: usability, forms, web-app, filter, user-expectation

Let's suppose an application that manage meetings between employees of various companies.
A meetings list is shown to any logged employee, and this one may mark himself as a participant if he's interested in the related topic.

To explain simply, I have a page listing all meetings matching some filters.

The type of filters are:

- filtering by nature of Job (engineer, manager etc.)
- only selecting the logged employee's meetings (no matter whether he's a simple participant or he is the meeting's creator) that are occurring at this time or will occur in the future.
- only selecting the logged employee's meetings that are already terminated (past meetings).

Both last filters are expected to be exclusive => both can't be selected at the same time.
If none of both filters are selected, matched meetings are those happening **currently or in the future**, no matter whether he's already participating.
Of course, those last filters should be combined with the job filter.

Here's a representation:

When employee selects the filter "My actual or future meetings", only those where he's marked as participant are shown":

[image]

When employee doesn't select any "My..." filter, shown meetings are those that are occurring at this time or in the future, **no matter if he's marked as a participant or not**:

[image]

When the employee selects "My past meetings", only finished meetings where he was a participant are shown:

[image]

I really want to keep all the natures of filters on the same page.

However, it sounds hard for any user to detect that in order to see meetings where he doesn't participate in, he should disable both "My ..." switches. It seems too implicit.

Furthermore, as by default past meetings are not displayed, I can't really consider the "My past meetings" being a filter, since it doesn't filter (reduce) the view, but adds past meetings.

Do you consider this design acceptable?
What would be a better way to represent the filter zone to increase the UX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just thought about this way:

[image]

or this way:

[image]

It sounds far more explicit.

Comment: Yes this is much better. You can try a radio button, which users are more familliar with.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use the first option including items filtered by only two tabs : - My pasts events
- All (default view)

In this last one you should include all the available events and those user participates to (this case assumes a different design from all the availables for instance different colors and/or a personal calendar view).

Comment: Suppose you've participated at 14:00 to `Meeting A`. 5 minutes later, they are **50000** newly created meetings. Would you really like to scroll over those 49999 in order to reach the one you are participating in? (meetings being ordered by date increasingly. With a "My actuals" tab, it would be far more easier to point the one you chose.

Comment: The meetings where user is involved to are supposed to be placed at the top list or in a clear personal calendar view.

Comment: As I want to keep the ordering by date (asc), I can't let the app move **my** meetings on the top freely.

Comment: Sounds weird to have 2 own tabs and one which is not.

Comment: That's the whole point.

Comment: That's why 2 tabs may be all what the user needs. It looks like strange if one tab ("all actuals") would display like thousands items and the 2 others only a few. I think that displaying 3 tabs is displaying too much information.

Comment: IMHO, my first comment answers your last one.

Comment: Could the past events tab be displayed by accessing user's profile instead of having a dedicated tab to it?

Comment: If it was a non-filterable list, indeed it could be. But I want to allow any employee to filter his own past meetings. For example, among my 500 meetings I accepted along the year, I want to retrieve those matching specific criterias. Employee's profile would be too heavy if I just duplicate the filter area in it.

Comment: What if you put the My Past events' tab at the bottom page of "My events" allowing the relevant filters ?

Comment: The reason is not so touchy:  I'm ordering **my actual weals** by date asc, and ordering **my past weals** by date desc. Mixing the two would break any ordering.

Comment: One tab (all the list) and a second one "my calendar" (calendar view where the user can "qtip" his own events and by a click zooming on the complete event he participates to). The past events should maybe be displayed only by clicking on the My events' tab (or My Calendar view) maybe on the left part. Past events's tab is not as important as the others IMHO.

Comment: How about a mobile view? Where you don't have so much space to display calendar view on the left.